# Intel XDK integration with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, business-logic, intel-xdk

I created a web app with Intel XDK, but now after I build the project I want to somehow open the build in Visual Studio and continue working on the back end of the app. That is, I'm designing the login screen with XDK and doing the business logic (e.g. database connections) in ASP.NET.

The problem is that when I build the app in Intel XDK, the main webpage is `Index.html` (not `.aspx`), so I cannot add any .NET code to it. How can I integrate C# (ASP.NET) code with the UI made in XDK?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your backend from your frontend. The Cordova application you create with the Intel XDK is a client-only app. The code is contained in and runs only on the mobile device. There is no "web-server" that is part of a Cordova application.

You should create a RESTful interface on your backend that you then use to communicate with the front end that runs in the Cordova app on your mobile device. Then use AJAX calls in the Cordova app to pass send and receive data from your backend.

In other words, these are two different projects.

Answer (score 0):

I do things opposite way.

First, create JavaScript application(I am using Jquery Mobile, but there are a lot of frameworks) with RESTful back-end in Eclipse (I am from Java side of power). 
For back-end I use Google Endpoints, but in .Net there are a lot of frameworks: Nancy, ServiceStack etc.

After application deployed to production server (GAE in my case) I take the front end source to Intel XDK and build mobile versions.

Next link can be very helpful in your case:

[Create a REST service using ASP.NET Web API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-rest-service-aspnet-api-sql-database/)